# How to pass the explode value in another foreach in PHP

Tags: php, foreach, explode

I am getting all the data from the database and one of my column data is `1|3|6|8`.

I am using explode to get the output.

Now, I have a checkbox list that I am getting from the database and I have to pass the explode value in the checkbox list to check the checkbox.

```
<?php 
      $exp=explode('|', $Info['recog']); //getting from the database
      print_r($exp) // output is Array ( [0] => 120 [1] => 121 [2] => 130 [3] => 156 ) 

      foreach ($exp as $key => $e) {
      print_r($e);
        }
    
     // displaying the list
      foreach ($checkLists as $key => $check) {
        ?>
     <li>
      <label class="regBox">
         <div class="mb-3"><img src="<?php echo $check['img'];?>" alt=""></div>
         <input type="checkbox" name="recog[]" value="<?php echo $check['cid'];?>">
         <p><?php echo $check['title'];?></p>
         <div class="checkmark"></div>
      </label>
   </li>
   <?php }?>
```

I know I have to use something like `foreach` and the `<?php echo ($check['cid']==$e['value'] ? 'checked' : '');?>`

Comment: Provide definition of `$checkLists`.

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal, in the $checkLists I am getting the image and title name from another table. I am displaying all the lists. I have to pass the explode value to this list to show the selected checkbox.

Comment: It says above `"print_r($exp) // output is  1|3|6|8"` ~ if that is the output from `explode` surely the output is an array and will not have the pipe char - so just `1,3,6,8`? So then why would `$e` have a `value` - `$e['value']`?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius, Yes my output is in array like  Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 [2] => 6 [3] => 8 )

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius, I just updated my output in the question and $e['value'] is the example. I am not sure what I have to use in that. So I used $e['value']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - I think that because the exploded string yields a simple array the inner `foreach` loop needs only to check if the current array member is equal to the `cid` field for the current record..

```
<?php 
    $exp=explode( '|', $Info['recog'] );
    foreach( $checkLists as $key => $check ) {
        
        $checked='';
        
        foreach($exp as $i){// simple integer
            if( (int)$i == (int)$check['cid'] ){
                $checked='checked';
                break;
            }
        }
        # Alternative
        # $checked=in_array($check['cid'],$exp) ? 'checked' : '';
?>
    <li>
        <label class="regBox">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <img src="<?php echo $check['img'];?>" alt="" />
            </div>
            
            <input type="checkbox" name="recog[]" value="<?php echo $check['cid'];?>" <?php echo $checked;?>/>
            
            <p><?php echo $check['title'];?></p>
            <div class="checkmark"></div>
        </label>
   </li>
<?php
    }//close outer foreach
?>
```

Comment: Give me some time. Let me implement your answer

Comment: Instead of `foreach($exp as $i) ...`, try this: `$checked = (in_array($check['cid'], $exp) ? 'checked' : '')`

Comment: Wait for a min. I think something is wrong from my side.

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal - that'd work too :-)

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius, Yes, it's working perfectly for me. Can you explain me this                                               if( (int)$i == (int)$check['cid'] ){

Comment: simply making sure you are comparing two integers... not strictly necessary though in this case. The approach suggested by @DefinitelynotRafal would also work.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius, Please, Can you also update the second option which is suggested by DefinitelynotRafa?  I will refer to both answers in the future.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius, I have to remove the if condition and add the alternative code. right?

Comment: Remove the ` foreach($exp as $i)` - replace with alternative version or use the foreach... both do the same thing in different ways